# Can I produce natbib-formated text from BibTeX file without a corresponding bibliography entry?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Is it possible to use natbib to generate formatted text from a .bib file, but not have the citation show up in the bibliography?

I'm using chapterbib and natbib to create a multi-chapter bibliographic document in the style of this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\include{ChapterFish}
\include{ChapterCats}
\end{document}
```

with ChapterFish.tex:

```
\chapter{Information About Fish}

\citealp{Fish1}: General information about fish.

\citealp{Fish2}: Overview of why fish are delicious. 
  For more information, see also \citealp{Cats} 
  in chapter \ref{ch:cats}.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{ref}
```

and ChapterCats.tex:

```
\chapter{Information about Cats}\label{ch:cats}

\citealp{Cats}: Study on eating habits of cats
  with regards to fish.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{ref}
```

and ref.bib:

```
@ARTICLE{Fish1,
  author = {S. Hark},
  title = {All About Fish},
  journal = {Foo},
  year = {2010}
}

@ARTICLE{Fish2,
  author = {G. Oldfish},
  title = {Fish Are Tasty},
  journal = {Bar},
  year = {2010}
}

@ARTICLE{Cats,
  author = {F. Eline},
  title = {Why Cats Eat Fish},
  journal = {Baz},
  year = {2010}
}
```

As written, the bibliography for the chapter 1 contains 3 bibitems: {Fish1}, {Fish2} and {Cats}. But this means that I have a reference about Cats in the chapter about Fish, which I don't want. I'd like to suppress {Cats} in the chapter 1 bibliography.

The trivial solution is to manually type the appropriator formatted citation for {Cats} in chapter 1.  However, I anticipate this issue will arise pretty frequently in my paper, and I'd like to use a more automated method to take advantage of my existing .bib file.

Comment: Just in case you are -- or a future reader is -- not tied to BibTeX: this would be pretty simple in biblatex.  (There are a few different ways it could be done, in fact.)

Comment: `bibunits` is compatible with `natbib` and provides such facility